# Spam text in MSSQL database

Tags: sql-server, spam

I have 20 and more MSSQL database on shared hosting. In 10 database I find spam text in hidden div:

example:

```
< div style="display:none">how to tell my husband i cheated <a href="link here">read</a> my husband cheated on me blog</div >
```

How find where is problem and stop it?

Note. Only I have a problem in 10 databse other is OK.

Comment: How do you find spam text in your database and remove / stop it?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu  I find text in all column and update, but after several days again come.

Comment: There are add-ons checking spam messages on WordPress, etc CMS tools. You can also create a list of banned words and check if the text includes any of those words. You can either replace those words with *** etc or refuse the post

Comment: This doesn't seem like a DB problem, rather a problem at application-level. A spam-filter, an add-on or something similar added to your app/website might solve your problem. The issue is not with the DB. Also, what is a `"half-base"`?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu  my mistake  "half-base" I have 20 MSSQL database on server in 10 I have spam, other db is OK.

Comment: You could create a trigger that runs every time a row is inserted into your database (PERFORMANCE HEAVY) and check the values with a simple regex and remove the html tags before the data is inserted.. But as @Eralper stated it would be better to check the values on the application level

Comment: @JoeJoe87577  currently I'm find 30 different spam div, every day come new....

Comment: So this text is in database? How does this gets saved in database? You need to check application and try stop this from happening in first place.

Comment: You possible have badly written applications that allow sql injection. Do some research on that.

Comment: @danish I don't know where this is coming from any site. On my site I have several form ex.(register user) + security code data from this form go to (register user table) but spam text I have in 40% table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the application.

the issue is not the db but the application inserting bad data and to solve you have only one way: identify the bad application and close the door to spammers.

so the solution is to identify the affected databases and then give a notice to the users to check their applications.

the data is not created by the db but by someone that uploads it using (guess it) an application.

a solution at the database level as a trigger may identify some of the spam but must be maintained regularly and will grow as you add more patterns to catch: imho is a waste of precious resources and of your time that is not effective in the long run.

Comment: it can be almost anything, it depends on the application. it may be a webservice that does not properly authenticate the users. or a form without captcha. or a cms with a bug.

Comment: a web form that allows sql injection